# Kotlin functional interfaces java compatiblity

Tags: java, function, lambda, interface, kotlin

I work on an application in kotlin, but need to have a good java support.
The problem I found are kotlin's functions.

this is what I used to do

```
fun test(loader: (String) -> Int)
```

but this will compile into a Function1 from kotlin library and since I don't have kotlin library directly included in the jar because of jar size, it makes it harder for java developers because they have to download the kotlin library to be able to use this method.

I tried to use Supplier or Function interface from java but I found it a lot more difficult for kotlin developers since you have to provide a lot more variable types and null checks and together with generic arguments it's a pain..

Also tried to create my own interface like

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface Function<in T, out R>: Function<R> {
    operator fun invoke(p: T): R
}
```

and function

```
fun test(loader: Function<String, Int>)
```

but it's the same as default java Function interface

so the only way that could work is to let the compiler compile my original function to my own functional interface instead of kotlin's one. But I don't have idea how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In kotlin 1.4 they added ability to define our own functional interfaces like that

```
fun interface Function<in T, out R> {

    operator fun invoke(p: T): R
}

fun test(loader: Function<String, Int>) {
    val result = loader("5")
}
```

Answer (score 8):

The problem you're facing is due to missing SAM conversions, see [[1]](https://readyset.build/kotlins-sam-problem-f315ffe6be3a), [[2]](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/kotlin-and-sam-interface-with-two-parameters/293/19) for more information. In short, Java allows you to treat interfaces with one non-default, non-static method as functional interfaces. If this conversion were present in Kotlin, Kotlin lambda expressions could be implicitly converted to Java functional interfaces such as `Function<T, R>`.

It's not possible to compile function literals to your own functional interface without changes to the compiler.

Your best bet given the status quo is to write a few conversion functions, which can be done very compactly in Kotlin:

```kotlin
object Functional
{
    @JvmStatic fun <T> toKotlin(supplier: Supplier<T>): () -> T = supplier::get
    @JvmStatic fun <T, R> toKotlin(function: Function<T, R>): (T) -> R = function::apply
    @JvmStatic fun <T> toKotlin(function: BinaryOperator<T>): (T, T) -> T = function::apply
    @JvmStatic fun <T> toKotlin(consumer: Consumer<T>): (T) -> Unit = consumer::accept
    ...
}
```

Let's apply this to a file Example.kt:

```kotlin
// passes an argument to the function and returns the result
fun call(function: (Int) -> Int, arg: Int): Int = function(arg)
```

From Java, you can then use them as follows:

```kotlin
import static yourpackage.Functional.toKotlin;

// in code:
ExampleKt.call(toKotlin(x -> 3 * x), 42);
```

Of course, if convenience is your goal, then you can overload your methods taking function parameters, to support both Kotlin and Java ways:

```kotlin
// Kotlin:
fun call(function: (Int) -> Int, arg: Int): Int = function(arg)
fun call(function: Function<Int, Int>, arg: Int): Int = call(toKotlin(function), arg)

// Java:
ExampleKt.call(x -> 3 * x, 42);
```

Comment: Thank you. I solved it by creating java version for aevery method that uses kotlin's functions

Comment: this looks like a great answer, but does not seem to work with latest version of kotlin, at least not in my case.

Answer (score 1):

> it makes it harder for java developers because they have to download the kotlin library to be able to use this method

JVM developers use build systems such as Maven or Gradle. Trying to manage dependencies manually is just a bad idea. And if any Kotlin-specific types are used in the implementation, the Kotlin standard library is still required.

Comment: Yes I know I'm trying to write the main API to be accessible without kotlin std-lib. And unfortunately I don't have my own maven repo so I they can't add my project as a maven dependency.