# Files.find() with BiPredicate in Kotlin

Tags: file-io, kotlin

I want to find all files in files tree. In Java I'd write something like:

```
try(Stream<Path< paths = Files.find(startingPath, maxDepth,
   (path, attributes) -> !attributes.isDirectory())) {
          paths.forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

But I am using kotlin, and came up with this:

```
Files.find(startingPath,maxDepth,
        { (path, basicFileAttributes) -> !basicFileAttributes.isDirectory()}
).use { println(it) }
```

However, this gives me error:

> Cannot infer a type for this parameter. Please specify it explicitly.
>
> Type mismatch:
>
> Required: BiPredicate< Path!, BasicFileAttributes! >!
>
> Found: (???) -> Boolean

Any idea how to use `BiPredicate` in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`BiPredicate` is a Java class, Kotlin function types are not directly compatible. This is due to missing SAM conversions, also explained in my recent answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51707129/5427663).

What you need to pass is an object `matcher` of type `BiPredicate<Path, BasicFileAttributes>`. To clarify, something like this:

```
val matcher = object : BiPredicate<Path, BasicFileAttributes>
{
    override fun test(path: Path, basicFileAttributes: BasicFileAttributes): Boolean
    {
        return !basicFileAttributes.isDirectory()
    }
}
```

This can be simplified to:

```
val matcher = BiPredicate<Path, BasicFileAttributes> { path, basicFileAttributes ->
    !basicFileAttributes.isDirectory()
}
```

When you pass it to `Files.find()`, Kotlin is even able to infer the generic parameter types. So in total, your expression would be:

```
Files.find(startingPath, maxDepth, BiPredicate { path, basicFileAttributes ->
    !basicFileAttributes.isDirectory()
}).use { println(it) }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `FileTreeWalk` for more Kotlin-ish way.

```
File(startingPath).walk()
        .filter { !it.isDirectory }
        .toList()
```

https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/-file-tree-walk/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You had two problems there. Use `BiPredicate { x, y -> code }` for the type mismatch error the compiler gives you, and then get the actually do what it intends to do by replacing `.use` with `forEach`. Otherwise it prints the stream object.

```
Files.find(startingPath, maxDepth,
        BiPredicate { path, basicFileAttributes -> !basicFileAttributes.isDirectory() }
).forEach { println(it) }
```

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin 1.4 works great with your original.

```kotlin
Files.find(MY_PATH, 1,
  { path, basicFileAttributes -> 
    !basicFileAttributes.isDirectory && path.endsWith("address") 
  }
)
.use {
  it.forEach { println(it) }
}
```