# "Type mismatch" when migrating lambda method from Java to Kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin, lambda

I'm migrating a class from Java to Kotlin but Kotlin converter doesn't convert lambda expressions for me correctly.

Here's my method in Java:

```
public static <V> void someMethod(Creator<SomeClass, V> creator) {
```

Here's my Creator interface:

```
public interface Creator<SomeClass, V> {
    T getPathFromUri(O o);
}
```

Here's how I implement it in Java:

```
someMethod(someVariable -> ClassA.methodA(someVariable.methodB()));
```

However, when I convert this to Kotlin, I get:

```
someMethod( { someVariable -> ClassA.methodA(someVariable.methodB()) })
```

But the error I get is:

```
Type mismatch.
Required: Creator<SomeClass, V>
Found: (???) -> ???
```

I don't understand what part of it has the wrong syntax. I tried to implement it multiple ways from the suggestions on other posts but I still get errors.

Comment: My understanding (and I am not 100% there yet) is Kotlin generics are a little different from Javas.  I think the signatures of Creator have to match... so either `Creator<T, O>` or `Creator<SomeClass, V>` but not both

Comment: @Gavin sorry, that was a typo, I had to make it generic.

Comment: No probs.... but that was all I had... good luck :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just when I had given up to post the question to StackOverflow, I found the solution: We have to explicitly call the type before the method, like so:

```
someMethod( Creator<SomeClass, V> { someVariable -> ClassA.methodA(someVariable.methodB()) })
```

instead of:

```
someMethod( { someVariable -> ClassA.methodA(someVariable.methodB()) })
```

Comment: And you can use `object` key word to create a anonymous class

Comment: For more explanation on this, you could check out my recent answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51876172/5427663. By the way, it's possible to accept your own answer if that solved the problem.