# kotlin: lambda as an interface implementation

Tags: kotlin, types, type-inference

existing spring's JdbcTemplate has signature:

```
public <T> List<T> query(String sql, RowMapper<T> rowMapper)
```

and i can call it with a lambda that implements the interface:

```
jdbcTemplate.query("select ...", { rs, _ -> 5 })
```

but when i declare the same function in kotlin:

```
fun <T> query(sql: String, rowMapper: RowMapper<T>): List<T> = TODO()
```

and try to call it the same way:

```
query("select ...", { rs, _ -> 5 })
```

i get a compilation error

> Type inference failed: 
>   fun  query
>   (
>   sql: String,
>   rowMapper: RowMapper
>   )
>   : List
>   cannot be applied to
>   (
>   String,
>   (???, ???) → Int
>   )

i have to write

```
query("select ...", RowMapper{ rs, _ -> 5 })
```

why? is there any way to just provide lambda?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Kotlin: Use a lambda in place of a functional interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33590646/kotlin-use-a-lambda-in-place-of-a-functional-interface)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Background

In Java, a lambda expression can be passed in a context where a *functional interface* is expected. Example Java code:

```
jdbcTemplate.query("select ...", (rs, _) -> 5);
```

In Kotlin, there is no implicit conversion from lambda expressions to interfaces. Rather than functional interfaces, Kotlin provides native function types with the syntax `(Params) -> ReturnType`. To make interoperability with Java easier, there is however a conversion from Kotlin lambda expression to *Java* functional interfaces, by adding the interface name:

```
query("select ...", RowMapper { rs, _ -> 5 })
```

### Solution

It's not possible to pass a lambda directly -- however you could write an extension function that takes a *function type* and forwards it to `query()`:

```
fun JdbcTemplate.query(sql: String, mapper: (A, B) -> Int) =
    query(sql, RowMapper { a, b -> mapper(a, b) })
```

This can then be called in the way you desire. Note that you *don't* need the parentheses around all arguments, due to the special syntax Kotlin allows for trailing lambda expressions:

```
jdbc.query("select ...") { rs, _ -> 5 }
```

See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51707129/5427663), where I explained this behavior in detail.

Comment: no, each of my invocation is kotlin. including the first one

Comment: That was a misunderstanding -- I edited my answer accordingly.